# Approaches for multi-field values

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I am using the Drupal 8 REST API to post content to a custom content type. I have a use case in which I need to post multiple values to a single multi-value field. If someone can show me how to do this it would negate my question.

As an alternative, I believe I could use the Paragraphs module to create a fieldset within my content type. I am writing to ask if someone can give me an example of how to post (or patch) my multiple values to the paragraph fieldset.

I should add that I do not know in advance how many values I will have in my multi-value dataset; it will vary by node. Its for that reason that I think either a multi-value field or a paragraphs fieldset might suit better than just creating additional fields in the content type.